# Bounce height of ball on Mars vs Earth

Tags: energy-conservation, potential-energy

I understand that if a ball is **dropped** on mars and on earth the ball will bounce back to basically the same height on both planets thanks to the law of conservation of energy. But can anyone prove this using simple mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy of the ball is given as $E = mah_1$ where $m$ is the mass of the ball, $h_1$ is the height over the point you set as zero potential and $a$ is the acceleration due to gravity (which is different between Mars and Earth). If you assume there is no energy loss due to heating of the ball or other inelasticities, you have an elastic collision which means all the energy is conserved during the collision. So, the potential energy is converted into kinetic energy $E = \frac{1}{2} m v^2$ with $v$ being the speed the ball had at the zero potential point. This kinetic energy is converted into potential energy again after the collision: $E = mah_2$. Since no energy is lost during the collision, $mah_1 = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 = mah_2$. In this idealized situation, the ball will jump back to the same height it was dropped from. This, of course, looks different in a real situation, where energy dissipates (air friction, inelastic collision, ...).